# Echo Nest API: limit tracks by one bucket only

Tags: api, spotify, echonest

I'd like to search the Echo Nest API for tracks which match various criteria, and get Spotify and WhoSampled IDs for these tracks. Importantly, though, I *only* want tracks which actually *have* a Spotify ID. I can use `limit` for this, but `limit` will also limit the returned tracks to those which have both a Spotify ID *and* a WhoSampled ID, which will dramatically reduce the number of results I get. Can I limit a query to tracks with Spotify IDs, and also optionally include WhoSampled IDs if they are present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=**your_api_key**&format=json&&artist=radiohead&title=karma%20police&bucket=id:spotify&bucket=tracks
```

Should give you echonest songs that have spotify tracks associated.
If you want to get whosample ids for the songs add

> &bucket=id:whosampled
>   to end of the query above

You can further limit the number of results with the `limit` parameter